# Como ver error exacto de una consulta X de SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una duda es la siguiente si yo tengo un PROC PERO DE MUCHOS DISTINTOS de SQL server envio unas variables pero el o alguno de los Procedure da error. mediante un codigo de x programa .exe que envia consultas varias y ocultas las cuales no son visibles solo se cierra los procesos de mssql y necesito ver donde esta el error. ejemplo de un codigo X que NO tiene nada que ver pero de error NO BUSCO (@chara) solo quiero ver donde se almacenan los registros de errores

```
  declare @char varchar(25) = 'name',
    @edad int = 18
    
    EXEC edad
    @edad, @chara
    
    CREATE PROC Char
    AS
    SELECT @Edad, @Char
```

Suponiendo que sean Miles de millones de consultas, procederes DISTINTOS y necesito ver donde se hizo el error que tabla o que Proc cometió el error ¿Dónde lo Veo? dicen que es algo con logs (creo que son archivos que registran los errores) pero el tema es donde los veo en `SQL server 2008 R2`

Answer (score 1):

Raiserror te puede devolver ese tipo de información.

```
Create procedure dbo.cuatro 
as
begin
    
    Declare @var int=0;
    -- aquí el error de división entre cero.
    Select 1 as result, 2/@var as divisonByZero
end
go
Create procedure dbo.tres 
as
begin
    exec dbo.cuatro;
end
go
Create procedure dbo.dos
as
begin
    exec dbo.tres;
end
go
```

Ahora creamos un procedure que llamará a dos y así sucesivamente.

```
Create procedure dbo.uno
as
begin try
    begin tran
        exec dbo.dos;
    commit tran;
end try
begin catch
    if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        rollback tran;
    
    -- Variables para recuperar información del sistema.
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSvr INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorStS INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorPrc NVARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @ErrorLne INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorNmb INT;
 
-- Recuperamos la información.  
    SELECT  
        @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSvr = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorStS = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorPrc = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        @ErrorLne = ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorNmb = ERROR_NUMBER();
 
--Asignamos el mensaje.
    SET @ErrorMsg = 
        CONCAT(
          N'Mensaje Personalizado: '
          , N'Procedimiento: '
          , @ErrorPrc 
          , N' - Linea - '
          , CAST(@ErrorLne AS NVARCHAR(100))
          , N' - Núm - '
          , CAST(@ErrorNmb AS NVARCHAR(100))
          , N' - Msg - '
          , @ErrorMsg);
 
    -- Utililzamos Raiserror 
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg,   
                   @ErrorSvr,
                   @ErrorStS 
                   )
            WITH LOG;  
    /* El parámetro WITH log, nos permite guardarlo en el 
    log de la aplicación */
end catch
go
```

En el procedimiento utilizamos un bloque try catch y en el catch recogemos lo que contienen las funciones **ERROR_PROCEDURE** y **ERROR_LINE**, para ver dónde ha ocurrido el error y presentar nuestro mensaje personalizado.

```
exec dbo.uno
```

[image: Resultado]

El mensaje de error nos indica, en Mensaje Personalizado. dbo.cuatro - Linea - 6, que es donde se ha producido el error.

Además en nuestra aplicación cliente, en el caso Sql Management Studio, disponemos también del error, gracias a la utilización de Raiserror con with Log

[image: Log Errores]

[image: Log actual]

[RaisError](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/15/raiserror-como-funciona-como-se-utiliza/)